# Left join multiple tables using lambda expression

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have 2 tables:

> specs {specId, desc, createdby, lastupdatedby}
>   users {userid, username}

I want the below linq query need to be written in pure lambda expression

```
    from spec in specs
    from user in users.where(x => x.userId== spec.createdby).DefaultIfEmpty()
    from updatedUser in users.where(x => x.userId== spec.lastupdatedbyby).DefaultIfEmpty()
select new {
spec = spec
user = user,
updatedUser = updatedUser
}
```

Please assist.

Data would be like say:

```
spec[{1, test, 1234, 2345},{2, test1, 1234, null}]

users[{1234, Allen},{2345, Dwayne}]
```

So the result should be

```
[{1, test, Allen, Dwayne}, {2, test1, Allen, null}]
```

Comment: Can you share list and you wanted result like table?

Comment: @Eldeniz I have just updated my question with sample data and result.

Comment: @RustinCohle please check my answer

Comment: @user449689 Thanks for the answer, but is that left join?

Comment: @RustinCohle no it wasn't supporting left join. I updated the answer: I spent some time working it out as I had never faced the problem. It was a very interesting exercice. Please take a look at the updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for your time. Its works. However is there a way to get the result without enumerating, directly from the lambda(selectMany) itself. I hope you get my question.

Comment: @RustinCohle I don't get it. Do you mean that you don't want to call the `ToList` method? You can avoid calling it and wait until the object needs to be materialized.

Comment: @user449689 No, I mean can we achieve the end result from lambda query instead of enumerating(which you have done in foreach)?

Comment: @RustinCohle of course you can, see my updated answer. I enumerated over the result variable, but if you prefer you can enqueue the `ForEach` method call just after the `ToList` method call at the end of the Linq query

Comment: @user449689 Yeah right. We can do that. I was expecting to do that before .ToList(), but its not possible I think. Thanks. I will stick with .ForEach.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's start with these classes:

```
class Specs {
    public int specId { get; set; }
    public string desc { get; set; }
    public int createdby { get; set; }
    public int lastupdatedby { get; set; }
}

class Users {
    public int userId { get; set; }
    public string username { get; set; }
}

class UpdatedUser {
    public int userId {get; set;}
    public string username { get; set; }
}
```

Now the Linq query, for convenience I have created some example data:

```
var specs = new Specs[]
{
    new Specs{specId = 1, desc = "Spec1", createdby=1, lastupdatedby=1},
    new Specs{specId = 2, desc = "Spec2", createdby=2, lastupdatedby=3},    
    new Specs{specId = 3, desc = "Spec3", createdby=3, lastupdatedby=1},
    new Specs{specId = 4, desc = "Spec4", createdby=3, lastupdatedby=3},
};

var user = new Users[]
{
    new Users{userId = 1, username = "User1"},
    new Users{userId = 2, username = "User2"},
};

var updatedUser = new UpdatedUser[]
{
    new UpdatedUser{userId = 1, username = "UpdatedUser1"},
    new UpdatedUser{userId = 2, username = "UpdatedUser2"},         
};

var result = specs
    .GroupJoin(user, 
        s => s.createdby,
        u => u.userId,
    (s, u) => u.Select(x => new {spec = s, user = x})
            .DefaultIfEmpty(new {spec = s, user = (Users)null}))
.SelectMany(g => g)
.GroupJoin(updatedUser,
        firstJoin => firstJoin.spec.lastupdatedby,
        uu => uu.userId,
        (firstJoin, uu) => 
        uu.Select(y => new {spec = firstJoin.spec, user = firstJoin.user, updatedUser = y})
.DefaultIfEmpty(new {spec = firstJoin.spec, user = firstJoin.user, updatedUser = (UpdatedUser) null}))
    .SelectMany(g1 => g1)
    .ToList();
```

The `GroupJoin` extension method help you obtain a tuple with all the elements of the starting table with a list of elements of the joined table.

Now if you enumerate the results:

```
result.ForEach(item => {
    Console.WriteLine(item.spec.desc);
    Console.WriteLine(item.user != null ? item.user.username : "NULL");
    Console.WriteLine(item.updatedUser != null ? item.updatedUser.username : "NULL");
    Console.WriteLine();
});
```

You obtain this:

```
Spec1
User1
UpdatedUser1

Spec2
User2
NULL

Spec3
NULL
UpdatedUser1

Spec4
NULL
NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
var list = specs.Join(users,
                s => s.lastupdatedby,
                u => u.userid,
                (s, u) => new { specs = s, users = u })
                .Select(x => new {
                    specId = x.specs.specId,
                    desc = x.specs.desc,
                    createdby=x.specs.createdby,
                    username=x.users.username

                }).ToString();
```

Answer (score -1):

```
LEFT JOIN MULTIPLE TABLES
------------------------

create table Rama(rid int,name varchar(80),zip int);
create table Kris(kid int,rid int, Title varchar(80),zip int);

insert into Rama values(1,'Robert Rama' ,10001),
                       (2,'Roger Raju'  ,10002),
                       (3,'Kevin Kali'  ,10003),
                       (4,'Mark Mutu'   ,10004)

insert into Kris values(0,0,'NP' ,10001),
                       (1,1,'VP' ,10001),
                       (2,2,'AVP',10002)

//Lambda expression
//Download https://www.linqpad.net/Download.aspx
//Create tables as given below and connect linqpad to your db
//select C#  statement(s) on linqpad and  run below
var v =
from r in Ramas
join k in Kris
  on new { r.Rid, r.Zip } equals new { k.Rid, k.Zip }
  into resultGroups
from k in resultGroups.DefaultIfEmpty()
select new { r.Rid, r.Name, k.Title };

v.Dump();
```